# How to add imperfection to material without texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

in cycles-render-engine, in a metal material, what is the best way to add imperfection (connect in roughness node) without add image texture?
Maybe a musgrave texture can help me?
Thanks
C

Comment: maybe this answer will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129316/is-there-a-way-to-make-slight-imperfections-on-a-model/129330#129330

Comment: and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3jnc3bHfNA) is a nice, to the point, tutorial on procedural scratches...