# How can I make a paint-covered material in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, procedural

So I'm struggling with the wheel rim's surface material and this is what I've done:

[image: my work]

The nodes:

[image: nodes]

(PBR material from Remington Graphics)

The real stuff:

[image: reference]

(For more references check [this](https://www.felgen-online.de/bbs-ch-r-schwarz) out)

So I'd like to have a little noisy effect to make the surface a bit rough and looks more realistic, for the current one it's too shiny (what about HDR?) and it seems too smooth.

I had some attempts before this question comes out:

[image]

But I'm not sure if it's a proper setup, and should it be the surface color, or height texture feeding roughness??

Comment: maybe this will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129316/is-there-a-way-to-make-slight-imperfections-on-a-model/129330#129330   and to make it less shiny on some parts, as I say, plug a Noise node into the factor of a Mix shader that mixes a Glossy and a less Glossy?

Comment: download the pbr shader version 2.3 from remington graphics, you are using version 2.2 which its the older https://remingtongraphics.net/tools/pbr-shader/

Comment: @moonboots yeah that really helps!